# Softlayer - list of servers which are powered on

Tags: java, service, hardware, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The following java code lists all the bare metal servers in softlayer for a specific SL account and filters for servers which are powered on (e.g. powerState='on'.

```
    public void listServers(Account.Service service, ApiClient client) throws Exception {

    service.withMask().hardware().fullyQualifiedDomainName().primaryIpAddress();
    service.withMask().hardware().hardwareStatus();
    service.withMask().hardware().id();

    Account account = service.getObject();

    //
    //  list of softlayer servers for the client account
    //
    for (Hardware hardware : account.getHardware()) {
        String hostname = hardware.getFullyQualifiedDomainName();

        String hardwareStatus = (hardware.getHardwareStatus() == null) ? null : hardware.getHardwareStatus().getStatus();
        Long serverId = hardware.getId();
        String powerState = null;

        if (serverId != null) {
            Hardware.Service hardwareService = Hardware.service(client, serverId);
            hardwareService.setMask("mask[serverPowerState");
            try {
                powerState = hardwareService.getServerPowerState();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error, cannot get powerState, hostname=" + hostname + ", msg=" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Hostname=" + hostname + ", hwStatus=" + hardwareStatus + ", powerState=" + powerState);
    }
}
```

Code seems to work, but for at least one of the servers, it fails on the call to hardwareService.getServerPowerState()

"Unable to establish IPMI v2 / RMCP+ session".

Any ideas why this is failing ?

Comment: The error that you got could be because there is not connection to the "ip address Management" or the IPMI is not configured correctly on your server. I suggest you to open a ticket  so they can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try opening a ticket for this problem